# Tried to load AngularJS more than once (After upgrading from 1.5 to 1.7)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am getting `WARNING: Tried to load AngularJS more than once.` after I upgraded Angular 1.5 to Angular 1.7

```
$stateProvider
    .state('sample1', {
        url: '/sample1',
        component: 'sample1',
    })
    .state('sample2', {
        url: '/sample2',
        component: 'sample2',
    })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sample1')
```

index.js

```
import sample1 from './sample1'
angular
  .module(MODULE_NAME, [])
  .component('sample1', sample1)
```

sample1.js

```
import sample1Html from './sample1.html'

function controller($scope) {
    // code
}

export default {
    template: sample1Html
    controller: ['$scope', controller]
}
```

It used to work fine when I was using Angular 1.5.

EDIT: As suggested by many online solutions I cannot use templateUrl as I am using components in stateProvider

// I cant use below structure:

```
    .state('sample1', {
        url: '/sample1',
        templateUrl: 'sample1.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl
    })
```

Comment: in your webpage, you are loading several times angular.js , you may have 1 angular.js via `<script src=".../angular.js"></script>` , and maybe one inside the bundle of your application (if you bundle-ifyed it).

Comment: I am not using <script> anywhere using angular package and I used to not have this issue when the app was AngularJS 1.5

Comment: When you get this error, open the browser dev tools and inspect the `<head>` and look for `<script>` tags, see if there are any duplicates of angular being loaded.  This must be happening somewhere, so if you can confirm it here then you can work backwards.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I can only see multiple `<style type="text/css">` (duplicates),

Comment: Well, this error only show up when angular is added twice, so it must be in there somewhere twice. Without us being able to see the app or the HTML, it's hard for anyone to tell you what to do to fix it.